# Flutter Geocoding, why showing error No address information found for supplied coordinates?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, geocoding

when trying to implement Geocoding to get address from Coordinates, i am getting this error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NOT_FOUND, No address information found for supplied coordinates (latitude: 23.837739, longitude: 90.366290)., null, null)
```

my functions to get the address from coordinates

```
  Future<void> GetAddressFromLatLong(Position position) async {
    print("PlaceMarks:");
    List<Placemark> placemarks =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    print("P:" + placemarks.toString());
    Placemark place = placemarks[0];
    Address =
        '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}';

    setState(() {
      Address =
          '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}';
    });
  }
```

How do i make use of Google Cloud Platform's Geocoding API ?
Does the Geocoding Flutter Package make use of this API?

using flutter v2.5.3 with null safety enabled

Comment: When working with long and lat - i usually double check two things - I make sure I dont have issues with permissions by using some simple code to retrieve the variables and then I also hard code some long and lat and pass them through global variables. Usually all problems go away when using these two or you get a more useful error message in the process. My 2 cents - good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is only occurring with my OnePlus 7T device, when i tried with other mobile devices, it works.

Comment: faced the same issues!. Thanks for confirming man that it is the device issue!!

Comment: Same issue in my pixel 4a